# React dangerouslySetInnerHtml not working in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to insert links into a composite react component. The `render` method calls a method `rowValue` which checks the state of the component and returns the appropriate markup to be rendered.

This is the `rowValue` method:

```
rowValue: function() {
    var fieldValue;

    if(!this.state.isBeingEdited) {
        fieldValue = (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={{ __html: this.props.value }} />
        );
    } else {
        fieldValue = (
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 js-field-wrapper">
                <input type="text"
                       defaultValue={this.extractUrl(this.props.value)}
                       className="form-control" />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return fieldValue;
},
```

On initial render the content of the div is empty:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" data-reactid=".1.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.1:$angellist.0.1"></div>
```

But when the `edit` state of the component is set to `true` the input is properly populated with the correct value:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 js-field-wrapper" data-reactid=".1.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.1:$angellist.0.1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://example.com" data-reactid=".1.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.2.1:$angellist.0.1.0">
</div>
```

Setting the `edit` state back to false renders the empty div.

Wrapping the `div` with `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` prop inside another `div` does not change anything.

Comment: Your div with the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is self closing - divs aren't self closing.

Comment: @Tom I'm following the examples on react's website [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) & [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (the last examle on the page) for example. On both the pages, the `div` with `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is self closing

Comment: Also, I just tested it out by adding a closing tag, still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you checked that `this.props.value` contains valid HTML?

Comment: [here](http://hastebin.com/talubudiyo.xml) is the content of `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` in the props of that div.

Comment: @Bhargav: can you prepare a fiddle please?

Comment: Sure thing, give me 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the exact conditions for why this was happening, but I found a workaround. For [posterity's sake](https://xkcd.com/979/) here it is:

I wanted to populate the div with a particular link. Instead of passing the string with the anchor tag to be set via `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` I just passed the URL and set the `href` attribute of an anchor tag.

```
  fieldValue = (
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
         <a href="{this.props.url}">{this.props.url}</a>
      </div>
    );
```